# java.lang.ClassCastException error

Tags: java

Normally whats the reason to get java.lang.ClassCastException ..? I get the following error in my application
java.lang.classCastException:org.sqlite.prepstmt cannot be cast to prepared statment

Comment: That is not an accurate rendition of the exception. Please be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

you are casting one type of prepared statement to other.
maybe you are using sqlite and casting to prepared statement of mysql? or from another library?
take a look at your imports

Comment: ok, how to solve it !?

Comment: look at your imports and remove the wrong one